# Installing crouton error

Tags: linux, chromebook

I'm totally new to linux, this is what I get? Am I doing something wrong, crouton is downloaded. I'm using an acer 710-2411 in dev. mode

```
crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ sudo sh -e ~/downloads/crouton
sh: Can't open /home/chronos/user/downloads/crouton
chronos@localhost / $
```

Comment: I think this is a fine question, but it belongs on Serverfault (unless there's another sysadmin SE I'm unaware of).

Answer (score 3):

folder name is "Downloads" not "downloads"
should enter: "sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton"

when entering a /folder/file path, you have to be absolutely positive about the capitalization, spacing, and underscores.(some tools dont like spaces in file_names_or_folder_paths, sees it as a | break in the instruction.

its always the easy things that get you first.
Dont be discouraged by the grandeur. welcome to the community.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same problem today. I tried running it again, rebooted, redownloaded it, and all. It didn't even work when I put it all in correctly (**D**ownload included).

I'm new at this also, but for whatever reason, it worked and brought up the help section when I simply omitted the 'sudo' (it then told me I needed to run as root, which is what 
'sudo' does). Afterwards, I ran it again normally (sudo -e ~Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t xfce) and it worked fine. Still no idea why but I hope this helps.

Comment: If you run sudo -e ~/Downloads/crouton, crouton will show the help text, because you need to specify a target. So what you were seeing was correct. As for why I did not work the first time, hard to say, but you have a typo in your second paragraph (should be ~/Downloads, you have ~Downloads), so it could have been a similar issue.

Comment: `Download` is still different from `Downloads`.

Answer (score 2):

Press ctrl+alt+T
Type shell.

Then use the following command to install Crouton: 
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce

If you're doing this on a Chromebook Pixel, change it to: 
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t touch,xfce

I ran into the same problem and thought the tool is broken. Turned out to be my typo. So, just copy and paste these lines. Crouton works.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Download the crouton file from here: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Download crouton from the shortened URL link near the top of that page: its the one that starts  https://goo.gl...

If instead you downloaded the crouton-master.zip file, and proceeded as normal, you would indeed get the reported error: 
'Can't open /home/chronos/user/Downloads/crouton'

Step 2.

Ctrl + Alt + T

opens a terminal.

Step 3. At the crosh> prompt type

shell

and then Enter

Step 4.
Run this:

sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce

(Assuming you want the xfce release and encryption)

The question was a while ago, but hope this helps anyone else arriving here with the same issue.